# How to filter time from a datetime to check if it is "Prior" or "After" of specific time in redshift?

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift, date-arithmetic

I have a datetime column in my table, and I want to create new column to check whether the time is prior or after 3 PM

The datetime is look like this:

```
date_time
14 March, 2023, 12:21
14 March, 2023, 14:49
14 March, 2023, 13:32
14 March, 2023, 14:07
```

The expected results:

```
date_time                  time_check
14 March, 2023, 12:21      before 3PM
14 March, 2023, 14:49      before 3PM
14 March, 2023, 13:32      before 3PM
14 March, 2023, 15:07      after 3PM
```

How can I do this with redshift query?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Redshift supports standard SQL date/time function [`extract`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html), which comes handy here:

```
select date_time,
    case when extract(hour from date_time) < 15
        then 'before 3PM' 
        else 'after 3PM'
    end as time_check
from mytable
```

If, for example, you wanted to show only rows whose timestamp is later than 3 PM, you would filter:

```
select date_time
from mytable 
where extract(hour from date_time) >= 15
```